# Mixing a custom php index page with multi-site installation

Tags: multisite

I am considering building a multi-site WordPress installation, but with the main page ([www.domain.com/index.php](http://www.domain.com/index.php))  a non-WP page. The site's main page will have extensive custom PHP code (with 'includes' of other PHP files), with links to other non-WP pages - like a 'landing' page.

The thought is to have the custom-build PHP page as the 'landing' page, with possibly other non-WP pages linked via a non-WP menu bar. Then there will be individual WP sub-sites (like [www.domain.com/site1](http://www.domain.com/site1) )that will be a standard WP multisite subsite.

The subsites must be one 'folder' deep, so not [www.domain.com/wp/site1](http://www.domain.com/wp/site1) . These sites may have their own domain name, which I know how to do.

How do I set up the domain's index page ([www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com)) to be a non-WP site, with the subsites as multisite instances?  I think that there may be some htaccess that needs to be done. Or do I have to convert the non-WP page into a custom template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first attempt used changes to the `htaccess` file , changing this

```
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

to this

```
RewriteRule . wpindex.php [L]
```

Then renaming the WP `index.php` to `wpindex.php`. My non-WP page could now be the `index.php` page.

This worked. *Until there was a WP core update.*

An upgrade of WP will overwrite the `index.php` page to the standard WP `index.php` page, negating all of our work. And it's possible that re-doing the Settings, Permalinks will overwrite the change to the `htaccess` file.

So I changed my approach. I decided to rename my non-WP index page to `landing.php` . Then I added this rule in the `htaccess` file (outside of the 'Begin/End WordPress' area of the `htaccess` file):

```
# Rewrite site root page to landing.php
RewriteRule ^$ /landing.php [L]
```

Now, accessing `www.mydomain.com` will show the non-WP `landing.php` page. That landing page can have links to other non-WP (or WP) pages.

Accessing a WP page with a slug of `new-page.php` will be processed by WP to display that WP page.

I'd be interested in other approaches to this. One might be to convert the landing page to a template, and then creating a page using that template. Or creating a landing page within WP. In my case, the landing page has other 'include' functions (a popup contact form) that makes using a template or WP-built page a bit more difficult.